# How to use a loop to conditionally create the value in a new variable

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have collected data about plant development or phenology (coded using a categorical variable 'Code') every five days along a transect broken down into 78 consecutive segments. Each species is surveyed across the transect in each of the segments. This effort is repeating a study from 100 years ago!

I would like to recode my dataset to overcome the deficiency of the original studies coding system.

Original Coding System (for the flowering stage of plants):

```
K = flower bud
b1 = single flower
b2 = sparse flowers (two or three)
b3 = flowers common (more than three)
B4 = flowering ended
```

The problem is that when I want to analyze my data these codes insufficiently describe the context of the observation. For example, codes 'b1' and 'b2' can occur both early and late in the flowering period. This makes it difficult to "rank" my observations in a standardized way.

The solution could be a loop or another efficient way to move sequentially through the observations (by 'Segment', 'Species', 'Date') to recode the observation based on whether the it occurs before or after a specific event (in this case the first time 'Code' is recorded as "b3").

For any given segment of the transect and species the codes might look like this in the original data:

```
Date    Segment Species Code
26/05/2017  1   A   K
01/06/2017  1   A   b1
06/06/2017  1   A   b1
10/06/2017  1   A   b2
14/06/2017  1   A   b2
19/06/2017  1   A   b2
23/06/2017  1   A   b3
28/06/2017  1   A   b3
03/07/2017  1   A   b2
08/07/2017  1   A   b2
14/07/2017  1   A   b1
19/07/2017  1   A   b4
```

If I had considered working with the data before the field season, I would have using a coding system like:

```
K = flower bud
b1a = single flower
b2a = sparse flowers (two or three)
b3 = flowers common (more than three)
b2b = sparse flowers (two or three)
b1b = single flower
B4 = flowering ended
```

With these changes to the codes, the example data above would look like:

```
Date    Segment Species Code
26/05/2017  1   A   K
01/06/2017  1   A   b1a
06/06/2017  1   A   b1a
10/06/2017  1   A   b2a
14/06/2017  1   A   b2a
19/06/2017  1   A   b2a
23/06/2017  1   A   b3
28/06/2017  1   A   b3
03/07/2017  1   A   b2b
08/07/2017  1   A   b2b
14/07/2017  1   A   b1b
19/07/2017  1   A   b4
```

Further, I have to recode the historic dataset so any solution will be critical for both.

NOTE: It is **very** important that the switch from appending an "a" to "b" for 'b1' or 'b2' occur after the **first** time a 'b3' is encountered. This is important because sometimes the data abundance of flowers fluctuates during the growing season. For example:

```
Date    Segment Species Code
01-Jun-17   1   A   b1
06-Jun-17   1   A   b1
10-Jun-17   1   A   b2
14-Jun-17   1   A   b2
19-Jun-17   1   A   b3
23-Jun-17   1   A   b3
28-Jun-17   1   A   b2 # appears out of the "ideal" sequence
02-Aug-17   1   A   b3
07-Aug-17   1   A   b2 # appears out of the "ideal" sequence
12-Aug-17   1   A   b3
17-Aug-17   1   A   b2
22-Aug-17   1   A   b1 # appears out of the "ideal" sequence
27-Aug-17   1   A   b2 
02-Sep-17   1   A   b1
07-Sep-17   1   A   b4
```

In this case the data would look like:

```
Date    Segment Species Code
01-Jun-17   1   A   b1a
06-Jun-17   1   A   b1a
10-Jun-17   1   A   b2a
14-Jun-17   1   A   b2a
19-Jun-17   1   A   b3
23-Jun-17   1   A   b3
28-Jun-17   1   A   b2b
02-Aug-17   1   A   b3
07-Aug-17   1   A   b2b
12-Aug-17   1   A   b3
17-Aug-17   1   A   b2b
22-Aug-17   1   A   b1b
27-Aug-17   1   A   b2b 
02-Sep-17   1   A   b1b
07-Sep-17   1   A   b4
```

A final note. Because of the short growing season here in the Arctic, not every flowering stage (=Code) occurs for each species in a segment.

Example data:

```
DT <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17312, 17318, 17323, 17327, 
17331, 17336, 17340, 17345, 17350, 17355, 17361, 17366, 17312, 
17318, 17323, 17327, 17331, 17336, 17340, 17345, 17350, 17355, 
17361, 17366, 17370, 17375, 17350, 17355, 17361, 17366, 17370, 
17312, 17318, 17323, 17327, 17331, 17336, 17340, 17345, 17350, 
17355, 17361, 17366, 17312, 17318, 17323, 17327, 17331, 17336, 
17340, 17345, 17350, 17355, 17361, 17366, 17355, 17361, 17366, 
17370, 17375, 17318, 17323, 17327, 17331, 17336, 17340, 17345, 
17380, 17385, 17390, 17395, 17400, 17405, 17411, 17416, 17318, 
17323, 17327, 17331, 17336, 17340, 17345, 17380, 17385, 17390, 
17395, 17400, 17405, 17411, 17416, 17318, 17323, 17327, 17331, 
17336, 17340, 17345, 17380, 17385, 17390, 17395, 17400, 17405, 
17411, 17416), class = "Date"), Segment = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), Species = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"
), Code = c("K", "b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b3", "b2", 
"b2", "b1", "b4", "b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b3", "b3", 
"b2", "b2", "b2", "b1", "b1", "b4", "b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b4", 
"b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b3", "b3", "b2", "b2", "b2", 
"b4", "K", "b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b3", "b2", "b2", 
"b2", "b4", "b3", "b3", "b2", "b1", "b4", "b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", 
"b3", "b3", "b2", "b3", "b2", "b3", "b2", "b1", "b2", "b1", "b4", 
"b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b3", "b2", "b3", "b2", "b3", "b2", 
"b1", "b2", "b1", "b4", "b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b3", "b3", "b2", 
"b3", "b2", "b3", "b2", "b1", "b2", "b1", "b4")), .Names = c("Date", 
"Segment", "Species", "Code"), row.names = c(NA, -105L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000000b0788>)
```

Comment: How do you distinguish which should be b1a and which b1b ? Because you have the same description

Comment: b1a or b2a occurs before the first time b3 is encountered and b1b or b2b after the first time b3 is encountered. I tried to clarify this in the text and examples above.

Comment: but then this change from a to b will happen for the same species for the same segment, right ?

Comment: Correct. We have the same species in many segments, so if the data is not sorted by Segment and Species the observations will be mixed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` this can be done the following way:

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>% 
  group_by(Species, Segment) %>% 
  mutate(after_b3 = (cumsum(Code == "b3") > 0), 
         Code_new = case_when(Code %in% c("b1", "b2") & !after_b3 ~ paste0(Code, "a"), 
                              Code %in% c("b1", "b2") & after_b3 ~ paste0(Code, "b"), 
                              TRUE ~ Code)) 

# A tibble: 105 x 6
# Groups:   Segment, Species [9]
#          Date Segment Species  Code after_b3 Code_new
#        <date>   <dbl>   <chr> <chr>    <lgl>    <chr>
#  1 2017-05-26       1       A     K    FALSE        K
#  2 2017-06-01       1       A    b1    FALSE      b1a
#  3 2017-06-06       1       A    b1    FALSE      b1a
#  4 2017-06-10       1       A    b2    FALSE      b2a
#  5 2017-06-14       1       A    b2    FALSE      b2a
#  6 2017-06-19       1       A    b2    FALSE      b2a
#  7 2017-06-23       1       A    b3     TRUE       b3
#  8 2017-06-28       1       A    b3     TRUE       b3
#  9 2017-07-03       1       A    b2     TRUE      b2b
# 10 2017-07-08       1       A    b2     TRUE      b2b
# ... with 95 more rows
```

With `group_by` the code is applied to each Segment, Species combination. The `after_b3` column describes whether the `Code` was already once `"b3"`. `Code_new` is then determined by checking several cases.

Comment: Would it be preferable to specify 'group_by(Species)' as 'group_by(Segment, Species)'? Your solution works because of the sort order of the data.table.

Comment: Yes you're right, I missed the point about the Segments and now changed my answer.
You could also add `arrange(Segment, Species, Date) %>%` after the `group_by` code to ensure the right ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most efficient way, but it works (taking into account that i understood your question)

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(DT)

tmp_list <- list()
for (seg in unique(DT$Segment)){ # seg <- 1
  for(spec in unique(DT$Species)){ # spec <- "C"
    tmp_list[[paste0(seg,"_",spec)]] <- DT[Segment%in%seg & Species%in%spec]
    index <- which(tmp_list[[paste0(seg,"_",spec)]]$Code=="b3")[1]
    rows <- nrow(tmp_list[[paste0(seg,"_",spec)]])
    if(!is.na(index)){
      tmp_list[[paste0(seg,"_",spec)]][index:rows,new_code:=ifelse(Code%in%"b1","b1b",
                                                                   ifelse(Code%in%"b2","b2b",Code))]
      tmp_list[[paste0(seg,"_",spec)]][1:index,new_code:=ifelse(Code%in%"b1","b1a",
                                                                ifelse(Code%in%"b2","b2a",Code))]
    }else{
      tmp_list[[paste0(seg,"_",spec)]][,new_code:=new_code:=ifelse(Code%in%"b1","b1a",
                                                            ifelse(Code%in%"b2","b2a",Code))]
    }   
  }
}
final <- rbindlist(tmp_list)
```

So by segment and by species, i find the first `b3` and after that **(and by after i mean for the next rows)** i change all the `b1` and `b2` to `b1b` and `b2b` respectively. For the rows before the first `b3` i change the `b1` and `b2` to `b1a` and `b2a` respectively. The if statements takes into account the case that a specific species segment combination has no `b3`